# Why is the scala-compiler.jar included as library in my artefact

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

When I build an artefact with

`sbt universal:packageZipTarball`

the scala-compiler.jar is included as a lib in my artefact.

1. Why is the scala-compiler needed at runtime? In my understanding it shouldn't be needed.
2. How can I exclude this jar?

Comment: It's possible that one of your dependencies depends on it. For instance to interpret some code at runtime.

Comment: If it is there I wouldn't recommend to exclude it, due to the what @Jasper-M mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably pulled in as a transitive dependency by one of your `libraryDependencies`. You can use this sbt plugin to find out which one:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph

Once you found out, you can block it by appending `exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-compiler")` to the relevant dependency.
For instance, older versions of the pureconfig library used to erroneously pull this dependency in. It can be fixed like so:

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.10.0" exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-compiler")
```